# Facebook Instant game review

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games

I'm trying to publish my game on Facebook Instant Game. But on step "App Verification Detail", it wants me to provide this "Please provide Facebook Login Integration notes that are at least 20 characters."

I can't anywhere to fill this information. if someone with similar experience could help me with some guidance.

Thanks in advance.

[facebook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMxpb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have In-app purchases in your instant game then you must write down the steps to explain the process in the **In-App Purchase Integration** textbox that needs to be **more than 20 characters** actually. If you don't have in-app purchase, then you can simply write something that says this game has no in-app purchase and make it upto 20 characters.

Next important thing is to **create a test app** in **Hosting Tests Configurations** section of **Web Hosting**. After you do this, the form will show you the test app in dropdown.

Another important part, create atleast one test user from Roles > Test Users > Add. This will give you randomly generated name user ID & email. Edit > Change username & password for this user. Set a simple password.

Now write those user ID emails password test user names and select Test User in the App Verification Details form with all the details you created now in simple English so that a human reviewer on the other end can understand when you submit the app for review to facebook.